# Need help sorting this logic with JSON Pretty Print

Tags: php, json, pretty-print

Trying to pretty print json, and works fine, cept, seems to add an extra line when printing out an array of objects between each object array.  Could use some help on the logic of this as I haven't touched this in awhile...

code for pretty printing it is as follows:

```
public function pretty_print($json_data, $line_numbers = true)
{
    $return = '';

    $space = 0;
    $flag = false;
    $json_data = trim($json_data);
    $line = 1;

    if (!empty($json_data)) {

        if (!empty($line_numbers))
            $return .= '<div class="line" data-line-number="' . $line . '">';

        //loop for iterating the full json data
        for($counter = 0; $counter < strlen($json_data); $counter++)
        {
            //Checking ending second and third brackets
            if ($json_data[$counter] == '}' || $json_data[$counter] == ']')
            {
                $space--;
                $line++;
                $return .= !empty($line_numbers) ? '</div><div class="line" data-line-number="' . $line . '">' : PHP_EOL;
                $return .= str_repeat(' ', ($space*4));
            }

            //Checking for double quote(“) and comma (,)
            if ($json_data[$counter] == '"' && ((!empty($counter) && $json_data[$counter-1] == ',') || ($counter > 1 && $json_data[$counter-2] == ',')))
            {
                $line++;
                $return .= !empty($line_numbers) ? '</div><div class="line" data-line-number="' . $line . '">' : PHP_EOL;
                $return .= str_repeat(' ', ($space*4));
            }
            if ($json_data[$counter] == '"' && !$flag)
            {
                if ( (!empty($counter) && $json_data[$counter-1] == ':') || ($counter > 1 && $json_data[$counter-2] == ':' ))
                    $return .= ' <span class="json-property">';
                else
                    $return .= '<span class="json-value">';
            }

            $return .= $json_data[$counter];

            //Checking conditions for adding closing span tag
            if ($json_data[$counter] == '"' && $flag) {
                $return .= '</span>';
            }
            if ($json_data[$counter] == '"')
                $flag = !$flag;

            //Checking starting second and third brackets

            if ($json_data[$counter] == '{' || $json_data[$counter] == '[')
            {
                $space++;
                $line++;
                $return .= !empty($line_numbers) ? '</div><div class="line" data-line-number="' . $line . '">' : PHP_EOL;
                $return .= str_repeat(' ', ($space*4));
            }
        }

        if (!empty($line_numbers))
            $return .= '</div>';
    }

    return !empty($return) ? trim($return) : json_encode(json_decode($json_data, true), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

But seems to parse the json with an extra `<div class="line" data-line-number=""></div>`

Here's an image of this and would like to get rid of the extra space between objects of the array in here if possible.  Any help here, would really appreciate it.

[image: json pretty print output]

Comment: This strikes me as a problem that would be better solved with recursion.

Comment: Why not just use the built-in functionality? `echo json_encode(json_decode($json_data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` if you have the raw data you could skip the `json_decode($json_data)` step.

Comment: @Nick - Because I require styling and numbers like in the image.  So, `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` does not provide this ability.

Comment: @AlexBarker - Would be highly interested in your approach to this.  Was thinking of the same thing, however, I keep hitting a wall on this.  Would be interested in a short example if you have the time?  Cheers :)  You can download the json file for this here if you need an example:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/59bnd6h3nkacjcd/eventlog-json.json?dl=0

Comment: @SolomonClosson do you have the original data, or just the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the heck are you manually parsing JSON? That code is going to be incredibly difficult to reason about and maintain, especially if you come back to it later when a bug almost inevitably presents itself.

Rather than taking the difficult approach, consider instead doing the following:
 1. Reformat the JSON so that it suits your needs. In this case, for example, you prefer to keep the closing and ending brackets of objects on the same line, rather than on separate lines.
 2. Split the already-pretty-formatted JSON into separate lines.
 3. Wrap the individual lines of your JSON in HTML.
 4. Re-join the lines to get your final HTML.

```php
function prettyWrapJson($json_data, $line_numbers = true) {
    // Ensure that our JSON is in pretty format.
    $json_data = json_encode(json_decode($json_data, true), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    // Modify the formatting so that adjacent closing and opening curly braces are on the same line.
    // Note: we can add a similar line if we want to do the same for square brackets.
    $json_data = preg_replace('/},\n +{/s', '},{', $json_data);

    $line_number = 1;

    // Coerce a boolean value.
    $line_numbers = !empty($line_numbers);

    // Split into an array of separate lines.
    $json_lines = explode("\n", $json_data);

    // Wrap the individual lines.
    $json_lines = array_map(function($json_line) use ($line_numbers, &$line_number) {
        // Check if this line contains a property name.
        if(preg_match('/^( +"[^"]+"):/', $json_line, $matches)) {
            // Similar result to explode(':', $json_line), but safer since the colon character may exist somewhere else in the line.
            $parts = array($matches[1], substr($json_line, strlen($matches[1]) + 1));

            // Wrap the property in a span, but keep the spaces outside of it.
            $parts[0] = preg_replace('/^( +)/', '$1<span class="json-property">', $parts[0]) . '</span>';

            // We only want to wrap the other part of the string if it's a value, not an opening brace.
            if(strpos($parts[1], '{') === false && strpos($parts[1], '[') === false) {
                // Similarly, wrap the value in a span, but keep the spaces outside of it.
                $parts[1] = preg_replace('/^( +)/', '$1<span class="json-value">', $parts[1]) . '</span>';
            }

            // Re-join the string parts with the colon we stripped out earlier.
            $json_line = implode(':', $parts);
        }

        // Finally, we can wrap the line with a line number div if needed.
        if($line_numbers) {
            $json_line = '<div class="line" data-line-number="' . ($line_number++) . '">' . $json_line . '</div>';
        }

        return $json_line;
    }, $json_lines);

    // Re-join the lines and return the result.
    return implode("\n", $json_lines);
}
```

You may need to tinker with it slightly to get it formatted exactly to your preferences, but this should be much easier for you to work with.

Comment: OMG, thanks, just needed to change the last line inside the function to `implode(empty($line_numbers) ? "\n" : "", $json_lines);` and that did exactly what I needed.  Thank you so very much!

Comment: Just noticed the comma at the end is inside the `<span class="json-value">` tag, is there anyway to put the comma outside of this tag, after it?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out with this bit of code:  `if(strpos($parts[1], '{') === false && strpos($parts[1], '[') === false) {
    $has_comma = substr($parts[1], -1) == ',';
    $parts[1] = preg_replace('/^( +)/', '$1<span class="json-value">', ($has_comma) ? substr($parts[1], 0, -1) : $parts[1]) . '</span>' . ($has_comma ? ',' : '');
}` Thanks again!

Comment: @SolomonClosson No problem! Honestly, even this solution isn't perfect--if the property name contains an escaped double quote anywhere within it, or a property's value contains either a curly brace or square bracket within text, then the logic will fail. Better validation could be performed here. Even better would be to decode the JSON into a data array and recursively traverse it as that would avoid the issue entirely and would be far more robust. Regardless, just be aware that this is a quick and dirty solution with all of the limitations that entails.